# How can I use Spring Data Neo4j to create a Node with new Relationships to existing Nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

My use case is that I want to send a Message from one User to another, by creating a Message node in between two Users. Here is the JSON I would like to send from the client, and my Message class:

```
{"text":"Hello!","recipient":{"userId":"1823498e-e491-45fa-95bb-782a937a00ba"},"sent":{"userId":"6467b976-7ff6-4817-98e0-f3fbfca1413e"}}
```

```
@Node("Message")
@Data
public class Message
{   
    @Id @GeneratedValue private UUID messageId; 
    
    @NotNull    
    private String text;
    
    @Relationship(type = "SENT",direction = Direction.INCOMING) 
    private User sent;
    
    @Relationship("TO") 
    private User recipient;
}
```

But when I call `Mono<Message> save(Message message);` in the ReactiveNeo4jRepository, the DB unique constraint complains that Users with those usernames already exist! It seems like it's trying to reset all of the other properties for those two userIds to empty/defaults, presumably since they're not included in the JSON. So I get a constraint error when it sees two "FAKE" usernames.

```
2022-03-26 14:34:29.120 DEBUG 51863 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-4] o.n.d.i.a.o.OutboundMessageHandler       : [0xb08eba68][x.server.com:7687][bolt-128] C: RUN "MERGE (user:`User` {userId: $__id__}) SET user += $__properties__ RETURN user" {__id__="6467b976-7ff6-4817-98e0-f3fbfca1413e", __properties__={lastName: NULL, credentialsNonExpired: FALSE,userId: "6467b976-7ff6-4817-98e0-f3fbfca1413e", enabled: FALSE, firstName: NULL, password: "FAKE",accountNonExpired: FALSE, email: NULL,username: "FAKE", accountNonLocked: FALSE}} {bookmarks=["FB:kcwQx2Hl5+KYQJiGdiyzOa4EWSCQ"]}
2022-03-26 14:34:29.206 DEBUG 51863 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-4] o.n.d.i.a.i.InboundMessageDispatcher     : [0xb08eba68][x.server.com:7687][bolt-128] S: SUCCESS {fields=["user"], t_first=2}
2022-03-26 14:34:29.207 DEBUG 51863 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-4] o.n.d.i.a.o.OutboundMessageHandler       : [0xb08eba68][x.server.com:7687][bolt-128] C: PULL {n=-1}
2022-03-26 14:34:29.301 DEBUG 51863 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-4] o.n.d.i.a.i.InboundMessageDispatcher     : [0xb08eba68][x.server.com:7687][bolt-128] S: FAILURE Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed "Node(1) already exists with label `User` and property `username` = 'FAKE'"
```

UPDATE: I can accomplish what I need to using an ObjectMapper from Jackson and the Neo4j Driver directly, as follows. But I still would like to know how to this with SDN.

```
    @Override
    public Mono<UUID> save(Message message) 
    {
        String cypher = "MATCH (a:User),(b:User) where a.userId = $fromUserId and b.userId = $toUserId CREATE (a)-[:SENT]->(m:Message {messageId: $messageId, text : $text})-[:TO]->(b)";
        Map<String,Object> objMap = persistenceObjectMapper.convertValue(message,mapType);
        return Mono.from(driver.rxSession().writeTransaction(tx -> tx.run(cypher,objMap).records())).then(Mono.just(message.getMessageId()));
    }
```

Comment: What happens to the JSON when it enters the application? Do you use Spring Data Rest or your own controller where this gets serialized into a `Message` object (as parameter e.g.)? In general this should work, assuming from the JSON that the userId is the UUID `@Id` field in the `User` class.

Comment: I'm just using a standard MVC Controller with Jackson. I'll take a look at Spring Data Rest. It's good to know that this should work, at least in theory.

Comment: It is easier to debug without SD Rest right now. So is the UUID I see for the user the `@Id` of the `User` entity?

Comment: That's correct. In my User class I have
`@Id @GeneratedValue private UUID userId;`
and there are also DB Unique constraints on username and userId. I edited the issue above to add some DEBUG log output.

Comment: I still can't figure this out. At this point it seems like it will be a better option to write all of my own cypher queries using the ReactiveNeo4jClient, although implementing the entity mapping on my own will be painful.

Comment: It would be ideal if @ Relationship annotations could apply to either complete entities, or just the @ Id values in the case when you don't want to pass around a bunch of data or modify the surrounding nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like it's trying to reset all of the other properties for those two userIds to empty/defaults

The problem you are facing is rooted in the handling of the incoming `Message` object.
As far as I understood this, you are directly saving the `Message` with the attached, de-serialized `User`s.

You have to fetch the `User`s from the database first. SDN does no pre-fetch. One way to do this is to create an additional repository for the `User` entity.

Given a `MovieService` that gets called by the controller, you would end up with something like this:

```
@Transactional
public Message saveNewMessage(Message newMessage) {
    UUID recipientId = newMessage.getRecipient().getUserId();
    UUID senderId = newMessage.getSent().getUserId();

    User recipient = userRepository.findById(recipientId).orElseGet(() -> {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("new recipient");
        return user;
    });

    User sender = userRepository.findById(senderId).orElseGet(() -> {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("new sender");
        return user;
    });

    newMessage.setRecipient(recipient);
    newMessage.setSent(sender);

    return messageRepository.save(newMessage);
}
```

Tested this with:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT username ON (user:User) ASSERT user.name IS UNIQUE
```

for 4.3 and/or for 4.4

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT username FOR (user:User) REQUIRE user.name IS UNIQUE
```

I created an example for your use case: https://github.com/meistermeier/neo4j-issues-examples/tree/master/so-71594275
There I also a user properties erasing call stack (`/clearusers`) that shows what I think happens in your application.

Edit: Since I usually advice not to create a repository for every entity class, you could also use the `Neo4jTemplate`. I have added the `saveNewMessageAlternative` to the example.